# Java language import command usage

Tags: java, import

> import mylib.utils

What is the path that import command in Java refer to in windows system?

Can I add my own library to that path?

Can it be in jar format ?

Answer (score 2):

You're confused.

The import has nothing at all to do with class loading or classpaths.  All it does is save you typing.  It lets you use short class names.

There's a `-classpath` command line argument when you start the JVM that is the right way to set CLASSPATH.  I would advise against a Windows environment variable.

Libraries should be packaged as JARs.  What else would they be?